# Check Postgres Listener is up/down?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, connectivity, connection-pooling

I am using PostgreSQL LISTEN/NOTIFY functionality in Java. So I have made a ListenerBean which is run at Application startup.

**LISTENER** class in java:

```
        @Singleton
        @Startup
        NotificationListenerInterface.class)
        public class NotificationListener extends Thread implements NotificationListenerInterface {

            @Resource(mappedName="java:/RESOURCES") 
            private DataSource ds;

            @PersistenceContext(unitName = "one")
            EntityManager em;

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NotificationListener.class);

            private Connection Conn;
            private PGConnection pgConnection = null;
            private NotifyRequest notifyRequest = null;

            @PostConstruct
            public void notificationListener() throws Throwable {

                System.out.println("Notification****************");
                try
                {


                    Class.forName("com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver");
                    String url = "jdbc:pgsql://192.xx.xx.126:5432/postgres";


                    Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","password");
                    this.pgConnection = (PGConnection) Conn;

                    System.out.println("PG CONNECTON: "+ pgConnection);
                    Statement listenStatement = Conn.createStatement();
                    listenStatement.execute("LISTEN notify_channel");
                    listenStatement.close();

                    pgConnection.addNotificationListener(new PGNotificationListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void notification(int processId, String channelName, String payload){

                            System.out.println("*********INSIDE NOTIFICATION*************");

                            System.out.println("Payload: " + jsonPayload);

}
```

So i make a `PGConnection` and start listening on the channel.

```
                listenStatement.execute("LISTEN notify_channel");
```

So I `NOTIFY` from the server when a Update of a table is done.

So when an UPDATE http request lands on my server and table is updated, I am not receiving any Notifications on my AS.

I have tested the same LISTEN/NOTIFY on `PgAdmin` and Notification comes when I run on Pgadmin's console `LISTEN notify_channel`.

Does LISTEN command goes down ?? How to check whether my Listener is up/down in Postgres ??